# How to add a download cancel button to download progress in android app

Tags: android

I want to let users to be able to cancel downloads. I have my download and progress bar working just well. I want to be able to add cancel download.. Here is my activity class code:

```
package com.afromusics.afromusic;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DownloadActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "Afromusics_file";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);



        TextView titlema = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Intent intenttitle = getIntent();
        String titlem = intenttitle.getStringExtra("blogTitleKey");
        titlema.setText(titlem);
         startBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
            startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startDownload();
                }
            });

    }

     private void startDownload() {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
            String url = fileUri.toString();
            new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);


        }
        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                return mProgressDialog;
            default:
                return null;
            }

        }

    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

        try {

        URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();

        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

        //Randow Number Works perfect
        //Random r = new Random();
        //int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
        Intent intenttitle = getIntent();
        String titlem = intenttitle.getStringExtra("blogTitleKey");

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/Music/ " + titlem + ".mp3");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

        }
    }
    }
```

And here is the Activity file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/cream_dustapp"
    tools:context="com.afromusics.afromusic.DownloadActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startBtn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/download_btn" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add cancel button in xml first then use in activity.

Comment: I know how to add a button in xml. The problem is how to get it to work in activity given the fact that the progress bar prevents any other action in the screen

Answer (score 2):

I think datos answer does not exactly what you want. It just cancels the ProgressBar. To stop the Asynctask I would do it like this:

Add a global variable to your Activity

```
private boolean running = false;
```

Then in your `onCreateDialog` Method add this between these lines:

```
mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
running = true;
mProgressDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //Cancel download task
            running = false;
            mProgressDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
mProgressDialog.show();
```

And finally in your `doInBackground`Method of your AsyncTask change these lines:

```
while (running && (count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
    total += count;
    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
    output.write(data, 0, count);
}
```

These will finish the AsyncTask or more precise the while loop. Make sure you are handling every post action on your ProgressDialog like dismiss in your OnPostDialog right. For example: The Dialog will be dismissed already.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use this example.

```
public class Test extends Activity
{
    public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
    private Button startBtn;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private final String KEY_TITLE = "Afromusics_file";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setButton(ProgressDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Cancel download task
                mProgressDialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```